# Getting click mouse position relative to UIElement

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, coordinates, adorner

I am trying to get the click mouse position on an adorner by hooking a handler on his mouse down event. The adorner is just a circle with 10unit radius positioned at the bottom right corner of a rectangle. I expect to get a coordinate in the range [0-10] for both x and y, but I am getting +100.
In the handler of the adorner I am calling e.GetPosition(this).

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that the position of the mouse pointer is calculated relative to the desired element with the upper-left corner of element being the point of origin, not the "center" of the element.
You have to calculate the position using the result retrieved from GetPostion(). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784139/easiest-way-to-get-the-angle-of-mouse-position-in-wpf-relative-to-the-center-of) an example

Comment: Ofc I totally agree with you, but for a 10 unit radius circle the possible range of values for coordinates when clicking inside the circle is [0-20], and I am getting more then that.

Comment: If you have a strange result, be sure that you are inside the adorner when you call GetPosition, because otherwise, it will return 0, or the distance to any other adorner

Comment: I am getting the position from the mouse down event handler defined in the adorner it self e.GetPosition(this)